# GROUP BY using spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am using Spotfire to build a line graph. The data set consists of the following fields:

```
Requirement Project Name    Period  Score   Project Spend  
Req 1       Project 1      3/1/2016 2       750000  
Req 2       Project 1      3/1/2016 3       750000  
Req 3       Project 1      3/1/2016 2       750000  
Req 4       Project 1      3/1/2016 2       750000  
Req 1       Project 1      6/1/2016 2       750000  
Req 2       Project 1      6/1/2016 3       750000  
Req 3       Project 3      6/1/2016 2       500000  
Req 4       Project 3      6/1/2016 2       500000
```

In the line chart, I have Period on X axis and I need `SUM(Project Spend)` by Project on Y axis.

For example:

- for 3/1/2016 on X axis, the value on Y should be 750000 as only one project is active (Project 1)
- for 6/1/2016 on X axis, the value of Y should be 750000 + 500000 as during that period two projects were active (Project 1 and Project 3)

Can someone help me with the Y axis formula to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If the value in project spent is always the same. You could do the following:

This only works with a bar chart though and not with a line chart. A line chart separates the lines so it won't add the values, even if you aggregate it by summing it up.

```
X-axis: [Period]
Y-axis: Max([Project Spend])
Color: [Project Name]
```

Alternatively, you could aggregate it by using a SQL Query if you fetch your data  from a database.

Comment: I do need separate lines for each project, It should just be one line showing the sum of projects for the time period. The real issue is that I have multiple rows with the same Project and Project spend so I can't use SUM(Project Spend) as it does Sum of all the values which is not what I want. I want the SUM of only the unique projects for that period

Comment: When you have multiple requirements per project is the value for project spend the same? If yes, you could perhaps limit the data in Data > Filter Data using Expression. 

Though I still think it is probably easier by querying it in SQL before importing.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to add a calculated column to keep only one row per project:

`[unique spend]: If(Min(RowId()) OVER ([Project Name])=RowId(), [Project Spend], null)`

Then create you line chart and use this expression for vertical axis:

`Sum([unique spend]) over (AllPrevious([Axis.X]))`