How to calculate a running total of unique user_ids over the previous 30 days in Tibco Spotfire?
I have a dataset that contains number of logins by user_id per day.  If I do a uniquecount([user_id]) in a cross table with [Date] in the vertical column, it gives me our Daily Active Users.  I want to create a 2nd column that is a running total of all unique user_ids over the previous 30 days (aka a rolling Monthly Active User count).  Is this possible to do as a calculated column or custom expression?
I've tried UniqueCount([user_id]) OVER (Intersect(AllPrevious([Date]), LastPeriods(30, [Date]))) but that just gives me the same values per day as uniquecount([user_id]).

Basically a group by scenario. Something like this with a COUNT rather than SUM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972337/group-by-using-spotfire

It looks correct, although you can simplify it removing the intersect
UniqueCount([user_id]) OVER (LastPeriods(30,[Date]))

If this is not what you wanted, can you show a sample of the data, current and expected result?
